# How is quantum computing viable if a single observation of the quantum system collapses entanglement?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Is the presupposition that an entire entangled quantum system will collapse with a single observation accurate? If so, how would we be able to leverage a quantum system to make computations?

Comment: One could perhaps wait and observe it _after_ it has done the computation...

Comment: The observation gives you the answer that you were looking for.  https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3

Comment: You both imply that a single quantum system is set up and destroyed for a single computation?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I really liked the article by the way, thank you